# Why am I not reunited with my deleted account here?

Tags: discussion

I accidentally deleted my Super User account. I asked [How can I download an age-restricted YouTube video to my computer, free of charge?](https://superuser.com/q/1386480/1065608), https://superuser.com/posts/comments/1733481?noredirect=1, https://superuser.com/posts/comments/1733477?noredirect=1.

But why aren't they in my Questions? Why do those questions still say  user711571?

Comment: Recently deleted posts can be accessed by a link at the bottom of the Answers and Questions tabs in your profile.  The question above was deleted more than 2 yrs ago, so even if it was in your current account, it wouldn't be accessible by normal means (there a SEDE script that will show links to them).  With a direct link to it, you should be able to access it, though.  If your old account is undeleted, it can be merged with your current account.  Merging needs to be done by SE staff (https://superuser.com/help/merging-accounts), and they can also undelete the account.

Comment: Why do you want deleted questions linked to your account.  Deleted questions can count towards a question ban.

Answer (score 3):

Deleted accounts are just that, *deleted*.

Any personally identifying information is removed and the posts from that account are effectively orphaned. They have a generic username attached to them but are not linked to the (now nonexistent) profile that created them.  Creating a new account does not recreate any information that can link the posts to you.

If you hadn't deleted the account then you could have merged them using the  [contact](https://superuser.com/contact) form where there is a system for merging accounts already set up.

If you really, *really*, **really** want those posts linked to your new account then you should use the [contact](https://superuser.com/contact) form and speak to the Stack Exchange team about linking those questions to your account. They may be able to help you but there would be some tricky work behind the scenes so this isn't something to be done lightly.

Otherwise if the questions are not all that important, especially the deleted ones, then you may find it easier to just ignore them and move on.

Comment: Said "tricky work" is usually not done by the team except under extremely exceptional circumstances.

Comment: @gparyani hence my emphasis on ***really*** wanting it done and *speaking* to the team about it. I make no commitment about it definitely being done, only that it is technically possible. Preference would be to simple shrug and move on.